# Edit Custom Links Menu markup: Making a Social Media Menu with linkable icons

Tags: menus, html, social-sharing

I'm creating a social menu media on my website using linked icons:

[image]

To do this, I'm using the 'Custom Links' section in Appearances > Menus:

[image]

The code snippet to achieve a linkable icon (I'm using Font Awesome) is this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/peakwebsiteservices/" target="_blank" title="Facebook: Peak Websites"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

As you can see, I'm using an icon tag (generated from the [font awesome website](http://fontawesome.io/)) and wrapping it in an anchor tag.

When I input this into the Custom Links dialog, I input this line of code under 'Link Text' and not 'URL':

[image]

The reason for this is to part and parcel of my problem.

Here is what the markup looks like for my social media menu when it goes live:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, I have the social media menu in an unordered list and three list items. Drilling down into the list items, you see *two* anchor tags. One anchor tag is empty and is created by the 'URL' field in the 'Custom Links' menu, and the other is where I input the line of code to create my linkable icons.

**I want to remove that empty anchor tag from the markup**. Does anyone know where/how I might do that in the WordPress codebase? Or is there another way you would do this programmatically without the use of CSS?

I imagine there is a function that outputs this custom menu somewhere in the codebase that I might be able to tweak to avoid outputting that first field. I'm hoping that I can tweak *only this custom menu* without affecting future custom menus, should I find I need to create others.

The other alternative seems to be using a plugin but I would prefer to not use a plugin for this. Can anyone speak to that?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong way, you need customizations for it.This may help you for this.

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'register_social_links', 10, 2);

 function register_social_links($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'top-header') {//Here you can use your menu theme location
       $items .= '<li class="your-class-name"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/peakwebsiteservices/" target="_blank" title="Facebook: Peak Websites"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! A question: how/why did you choose 'wp_nav_menu_items'? 

When I use this hook, I no longer see <li> tags and all the corresponding classes that get attached to them (menu-item menu-item-type-custom etc...) in my menu markup.

Is there a resource you recommend for getting an overview of the available function to hook into?

Thanks again, Dave.

Comment: I understand I can add li tags back in by adding them to the string values but I still lose all the standard classes. Is there any way to put the classes back in?

Comment: see I updated the answer, you may add <li> and your standard class name to it. ;)