# child theme font awesome icons not working

Tags: menus

I created custom social media icons menu as recommended [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365257/footer-php-twentysixteen-child-theme-social-links-menu-to-output-font-awesom), using custom links and optional CSS class.

my child theme footer.php currently has

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
            <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'social',
                            'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                            'depth'          => 1,
                            'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                            'link_after'     => '</span>',
                        )
                    );
                ?>
            </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Following is the output I am getting in my child theme

[image]

Following is the output by the parent theme

[image]

Parent theme uses attribute selector combined with pseudo element to insert font awesome icon before the anchor tag

`.social-navigation a[href*="codepen.io"]:before {
    content: "\f216";
}`

I didn't enqueue parent CSS files as I am using my own CSS for styling and layout.

My question is how can I use the above to produce same font awesome icons output in my child theme

**I adjusted wp_nav_menu in child theme footer.php to**

```
        <?php
          wp_nav_menu(
            array(

          'theme_location'    => 'social',
          'container'         => 'false',
          'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
          'link_after'     => '</span>',
           )
         );
        ?>
```

which produces the following output, however, the icons are not clickable

```
<footer class="footer">


<ul id="menu-social" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-218" class="fab fa-github menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218"><a href="https://github.com/810311"><span class="screen-reader-text">github</span></a></li>
</ul>       

</footer>
```

Comment: Include your code so someone can actually see what's going on.  It's fine that you shared the link that you used to build it, but no one can tell what you did or what other elements may be interfering.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for the quick response. I have edited my question to include the code and the output I am getting. Please take a look when you have time.

Comment: I've updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, make sure you have this rule:

```
.screen-reader-text{
     display:none;
}
#menu-social li[class*='fa-']:before{
     content:'';
}
#menu-social li[class*='fa-codepen'] > a:before{
     content:'\f1cb';
}
#menu-social li[class*='fa-github'] > a:before{
     content:'\f09b';
}
#menu-social li[class*='fa-youtube'] > a:before{
     content:'\f167';
}
```

What you're seeing is labels intended to improve accessibility for the visually impaired so that their screen reader knows what to read.  That probably already exists in the parent theme CSS but since you're not including the instruction it's still showing the labels.

**Update**

I've added new selectors that will target the `<a href="">` instead of targeting the `<li>`.  This way, you can still add the classes for fontawesome to the `<li>` tags but then output the icons `:before` or `:after` the `<a href="">`.  It's really just a matter of going one level deeper with your selectors.

Comment: I understand we can hide the link text. Current icons are not links. I am not sure if its possible using CSS only to make font awesome icon clickable since they would have to be inserted within anchor tags in html output. I did more research and found the following  [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285260/edit-custom-links-menu-markup-making-a-social-media-menu-with-linkable-icons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285260/edit-custom-links-menu-markup-making-a-social-media-menu-with-linkable-icons)

Comment: I tried using atribute selector with 'after' pseudo element as suggested by @WebElain (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355979/text-symbols-in-the-navigation-menu) but it just inserts duplicate icon next to the one produced by font awesome class. I tried removig the class from custom menu but it removes both icons leaving a square instead

Comment: You realize that your screen shots don't really explain that the issue you're having is that the icons aren't links?  Please try to be a bit clearer with your question.  Can you include the HTML output for one of the links that your `wp_nav_menu()` generates?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the confusion. I've edited my question

Comment: Ok, I have a fix for this but quick question, what's adding the `fa fab fa-github` to the `<li>` elements - are you just doing that through adding classes in the menu admin?

Comment: 'are you just doing that through adding classes in the menu admin? ' correct

Comment: Thanks Tony. It works now - links are clickable. However, I now have two sets of icons showing - one added by `fab fa-github` in the admin and one by your CSS

Comment: That just means there’s other CSS adding it, so you’d need to locate and remove the other style rules.  Or, a quick and simple clean-up would be to use li.fa-* selector and set that content to ‘’;  I actually added it to my answer.

Comment: The first set of icons is added by `fab fa-github` class which I add via custom menu. When I try to remove that class from custom menu,  both github icons disappear

Comment: See my updated answer.  You have to have the class in the menu item, what I meant was that you needed to remove the style rules from the CSS that were adding it.  But my solution added to the answer gives you a simple override.

Comment: I saw your updates. I've added that override - first set of icons is gone now.Thanks Tony `. fa-github:before{content:"\f09b"}` is the class added via font awesome external stylesheet which I have linked via functions.php so I guess your override is the only good solution for this type of scenario

Comment: The alternative would be to edit the fontawesome.css but then it won’t work elsewhere.  If your question’s been answered remember to click the check mark so future searches will know this works.

Comment: I agree with your last comment. Thanks again Tony. I check marked your answer.